# Back button filter not working

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, back-button

I have configured a filter to disable my browser back button and show the user as session expired. It is working as expected when I configure that in my application prototype but when I incorporated it to my (spring MVC) application it is not working.

I have configured my filter like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>backButtonFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.filters.BackButtonFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>backButtonFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and I had my filter contents like this

```
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Cache-Type", "private");
```

I have introduced the log statement to see if my filter is getting executed or not. I can see it executing.

Why is it happening so?

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check out the HTTP headers on the browser end? That should make it easier to see why they're not working as intended.

**EDIT** One thing to watch out for, make sure the HTTP headers are all being written out before the HTTP body.

Comment: I not not aware of fire bug. I will try to track this

Answer (score 0):

Try Configuring an interceptor inside Servlet Context as this:

```
<!--  configuration for handling browser back button  -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*"/>
        <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But whether session is live or not, it should be verified or handled in your view (HTML or JSP). You can have the following meta tags in your view to say no-cache and no-store

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

or

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="No-Cache,Must-Revalidate,No-Store">
```

If you submit your form with GET, the user always can go to the resulting screen by hitting the back button.

If you use POST, the browser will say that this may not be possible.